# Weblogic: how to replicate server configuration?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

We're setting up a development team, where we want each developer to run its copy of Weblogic in their workstations.

Ideally, we would like all these installs to be as similar to the production environment as possible. Things like:

- port numbers of servers
- Admin and managed servers
- JDBC data sources and JNDI names
- JMS data sources
- Additional jars in the classpath

I would like to set the server once and replicate the configuration to everyone on the team.

Is there a way to share this kind of configuration accross the team ? Maybe share some config files ? Some Weblogic jython script that recreates the environment ? How to do it ?

Weblogic version is Weblogic 12c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create new empty domain using [standard tools](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24499/newdom.htm#WLDCW194) (don't start it!)
2. Init Git repository
3. Commit the following folders and files:

   - bin/
   - config/
   - security/
   - fileRealm.properties
   - startWebLogic.cmd
   - startWebLogic.sh
4. [Create file](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/15-BootProp--4471/bootproperties.htm) `servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties` for easier server start up and commit it.
5. In `startWebLogic.cmd` make `DOMAIN_HOME` relative:
   `set DOMAIN_HOME=%~dp0`
6. Remove absolute paths declarations in the files:

   - bin/setDomainEnv.cmd
   - bin/startManagedWebLogic.cmd
   - bin/startWebLogic.cmd
   - bin/stopManagedWebLogic.cmd
   - bin/stopWebLogic.cmd
7. Start weblogic domain by click on `startWeblogic.cmd`
8. Add JDBC and JMS settings via Administration Console. Commit only `config/` folder and changed files (not new): `git add config` and `git add -u`
9. Place additional jars into `lib/` folder and commit.
10. Share the repository with other people.

See [example repository](https://github.com/slavashvets/weblogic_domain_12c) on github.

Comment: Thanks ! Care to elaborate on the standard tools on item 1 ? Is that command line or the web admin console ?

Comment: Sure. I've added the link to the official docs. See "Creating a WebLogic Domain in Graphical Mode"

Comment: It's also possible to create new domain using scripts (`unpack` command), but this will be a little bit of overhead for such one-time actions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using [biemond/orawls](https://forge.puppet.com/biemond/orawls). An example of how to use it is [available here](http://middlewaresnippets.blogspot.com.au/2015/03/install-and-configure-weblogic-server.html).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is addressed by infrastructure configuration automation tools, such as [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [Puppet](https://puppet.com/) and [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/).

Having an authoritative environment configuration defined using one of these tools can be not only useful for [development environment](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/infrastructure-automation-of-development-workstations) setup purposes, but also for any other production or non-production environments.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has recommended to use pack/unpack to extend domain. Both the commands are easy to use and can be executed easily